# Does the Linux 'nice' command work on any shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, nice

Does `nice` work on any shell script,  or does it work on basic Linux commands only?

For example, if I have a custom shell script that contains a `sort` function, and I call

```
nice myscript.sh
```

would the `nice` scheduling priority apply to `sort` in the script?
Would `nice` still work if `myscript.sh` is running in the background (using `&` or `nohup`)?

Comment: As others have said, the simple answer is yes. The children will inherit niceness from the parent. As demonstrated here: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/96715-using-nice-script.html#post479756

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `nice` command can be used with scripts. Actually, assuming you are using bash, the nice command will be applied to bash and all its possible child processes. The nice priority is not altered when a process is running on the background.

You can just test it yourself and see that nice indeed affects the priority of a bash script. Just execute any script you want, and then use `ps` to see the priorities:

```
ps -eo pid,pri,cmd
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice applies to the process that is started when running the command and any child processes. So the answer to your question is yes, it does work on any commands/scripts, even if they are put into the background.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `nice` works with scripts, for example:

```
nice ./example.sh
```

If you want to adjust the scheduling priority using a command within a script, you can use `renice`. Here are the contents of an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world"
renice -n 10 -p $$
echo "Now the niceness value has been changed to 10."
```

Niceness values range from -20 (most favorable to the process) to 19 (least favorable to the process).